# Create pyqt5 pushbuttons with click event using loop

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How Can I Create PushButtons With connect using loop

```
list = ['apple','orange','banana','carrot']
for i,s in enumerate(list)
    list[i] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    list[i].setText(s[0])
    list[i].clicked.connect(lambda:getbuttontext(list[i].text()))
```

and Here Is getbuttontext function:

```
def getbuttontext(n):
    print(n)
```

> My Problem Is That When I Click On Any button the Function print "carrot"
>   How To Fix It Please...

Comment: Please edit your question and add a real question. It's not clear what you are asking...

Comment: What is your question? What does PHP have to do with your question?

Comment: Give Me A Function That Print The Text Of Each button inside the loop

Comment: @Derar  What buttons, and what loop? Also show what you have tried to solve it, read the SO rules: [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple, define the input parameters of the lambda function:

```
fruits = ['apple','orange','banana','carrot']
for i,s in enumerate(fruits)
    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    btn.setText(s[0])
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda checked, text=s : getbuttontext(text))
```

**Note:**
I put checked because it is the parameter that passes the clicked signal by default.

Comment: @Derar Check my current answer, you should not use list to store strings and buttons. also list is a reserved word

Comment: TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'checked'
, also without checked, it just gave false value

Comment: @FoggyMindedGreenhorn Sure you are using PySide2, try `btn.clicked.connect(lambda *args, text=s : getbuttontext(text))` OR `btn.clicked[bool].connect(lambda checked, text=s : getbuttontext(text))`, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185005/error-lambda-missing-1-required-positional-argument-when-using-with-qpushbutton/65185119#65185119

Comment: thanks, it works!  yes, I use PySide2, sorry, I thought they have the same behavior on this matter, didn't think that far tbh @eyllanesc

Comment: @eyllanesc, why do you need enumerate?

Answer (score 1):

lambda doesnt store the value of button ,instead you can use another method

```
from functools import partial
for i in range(10):
  btn[i].clicked.connect(patial(getbuttontext,btn[i].text()))
```